# How to record left and right hand as separate tracks in Cakewalk?

Tags: recording, midi, multichannel

I have some midi files that when played in Cakewalk, I can see that the left and right hands are separate tracks.

I have seen in programs like PlayPerfect and MIDIculous, the software attempts to guess left/right and color codes.

How can I do record left/right hands as separate tracks in Cakewalk?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want literally separate hands, as opposed to a simple split point, then you'd either need to record each hand separately, or use 2 keyboards simultaneously, one to each track/channel.

Alternatively, split it out manually after the recording.

If you have additional pedal data, then either you'd need to split that too, or output both tracks on the same channel, so they will share the pedal.